# Remove individual points and find slope

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, pandas, numpy

I am trying to delete one pair of x and y coordinates from a set of 10 data points and get the slope for the other 9 points.

How do I go about this issue?

Attached herewith is an image of what I am trying to figure out:

[image: Dataset]

In the above image, column B is x-axis and column C is y-axis.

Column D has multiple slopes for every datapoint removed.

The comment section says how each slope was obtained.

Example: Slope of 0.3741 was obtained by removing out B6 and C6 from the dataset.

This is an extremely challenging topic for me to figure out which path to follow. Any help on this aspect is deeply appreciated.

---

It is similar to go find a pair of x and y coordinates, delete the pair and then give the slope of the other 9 points.

---

Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you're looking for a software-only answer, please post this question on [SO].  If you're looking for an analysis, explanation, and/or formula, then you have come to the right place here on CV.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like more of a StackOverflow question than CV. If you're using pandas, you can use `pandas.DataFrame.drop`, or you can take a slice. For instance, one way of doing this would be

```
 df['Output slope'] = [find_slope(df.loc[df.index !=i]) for i in df.index]
```

Where `find_slope` is whatever algorithm you're using to find the slope.

Comment: @Accumulation, thanks for the reply. I get confused many times as to which forum to post to. Thanks for guiding me this time :)